# Calling another function asynchronously and never wait it to finish in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, chatbot

I am working on a chatbot, where before I reply to the user I make a DB call to save the chat in a table. This will be done each time user types something, and it increases the response time.

So to decrease the response time, we need to call this `asynchronously`.

How to do this in Python 3?

I have read tutorials of `asyncio` library, but did not understand it completely and could not understand how to make it work.

Another workaround is to use queuing system, but that sounds like an overkill.

**Example:**

```
request = get_request_from_chat
res = call_some_function_to_prepare_response()
save_data() # this will be call asynchronously
reply() # this should not wait save_data() to finish
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did my solution resolved your issue?

Comment: Did any of the answers helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loop.create_task(some_async_function())` to run an async function "in the background". For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51646817/1600898) shows how to do that in case of a trivial client-server communication.

In your case the pseudo-code would look like this:

```
request = await get_request_from_chat()
res = call_some_function_to_prepare_response()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(save_data()) # runs in the "background"
reply() # doesn't wait for save_data() to finish
```

For this to work, of course, the program must be written for asyncio and `save_data` must be a coroutine. For a chat server it's a good approach to follow anyway, so I would recommend to give asyncio a chance.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you please explain `program must be written for asyncio`

Comment: @sid8491 It means that it must run in the asyncio event loop, use coroutines etc. Refer to a good tutorial for details, see e.g. [this list.](https://morestina.net/blog/1213/asyncio-reading-list)

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned

> Another workaround is to use queuing system, but that sounds like an
>   overkill.

I assume you are open to other solutions so I will propose multi-threading approach:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep


def long_runnig_funciton(param1):
    print(param1)
    sleep(10)
    return "Complete"



with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(long_runnig_funciton,["Param1"])


print(future.result(timeout=12))
```

Steps:

1) You create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and define maximum number of concurrent tasks.

2) You submit a function with arguments it needs

3) You call `result()` on the return value from `submit()` when you need the results

Note that the `result()` can throw exception if exception was thrown in the submitted function

You can also check if the result of your call is ready with `future.done()` which returns `True` or  `False`

Comment: this seems good, i'll try this now and post any doubts if any